# Google App Engine Prospective Search Subscriptions Exceeded Quota

Tags: android, google-app-engine

My app has recently been featured on a popular Android forum and it's brought a huge amount of traffic that I wasn't expecting. The only quota I've gone over is Prospective Search Subscriptions and it seems like there's no way to increase that quota through billing or otherwise, so the app will be unusable until the quota resets in 16 hours.

My app has been reporting this stack trace:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
{
    "code": 403,
    "errors": [
    {
        "domain": "global",
        "message":
    "com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$OverQuotaException: The API call matcher.Subscribe() required more quota than is available.",
        "reason": "backendError"
    }
    ],
    "message":
"com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$OverQuotaException: The API call matcher.Subscribe() required more quota than is available."
}
```

Is there anything I can do to increase the quota or otherwise have the backend continue running before the quota is reset?

Comment: Is the API vital to your app? If not - could you simply catch the exception, notify the user about that part being currently unavailable and go on with the rest of the app since one unavailable API doesn't have to take your whole app down. Also, [Google will usually increase any of the limits](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#When_a_Resource_is_Depleted), even on free apps if you give them a good reason but don't expect them to get back to you in less than a week.

Comment: The app is nothing without the API since it relies entirely on it. I'll check out your link.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing#change_budget) you can set a daily budget to increase your quota.

Comment: I don't think that makes any difference for the experimental Prospective Search API for which there is no pricing yet. At least it used to be that way IIRC.

Comment: Mihail is correct. I have billing enabled but no charges have been incurred.